# XmlPullParser in Android

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

I want to parse xml from [this rss feed](http://lib.must.edu.mo/en/newarrivals/feed?quicktabs_common_links=2), but I just get things like this:

"New Arrivals

Last updated:May 28 6:45PM"

I don't have enough reputation so I can just post words instead of an image. Please excuse me.

I am really a fresh man in Android, so I copied the code from [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html) website and make some changes to parse the above xml data. I read others' questions and think that the problem is about the "channel" tag, but after some modification, nothing changed. Here is the core code:

```
private List<Entry> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "rss");

    parser.next();//I add this statement to pass the channel tag but it doesn't work

    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        String name = parser.getName();
       if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        // Starts by looking for the entry tag
        if (name.equals("item")) {
            entries.add(readEntry(parser));
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return entries;
}

private Entry readEntry(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "item");
    String title = null;
    String description = null;
    String link = null;
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        if (name.equals("title")) {
            title = readTitle(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("description")) {
            description = readDescription(parser);
        } else if (name.equals("link")) {
            link = readLink(parser);
        } else {
            skip(parser);
        }
    }
    return new Entry(title, description, link);
}
```

I'll appreciate it if anyone could help.

Comment: Try to change "rss" to "channel" in your parser initialization : parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "channel");

Comment: I did it but this time nothing appear at all. Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you try debugging ?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, "New Arrival" is post by myself, not the result of parsing. So now actually I get nothing. I think I'd better read the tutorial on android.com carefully.

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419288/stuck-with-xmlpullparser-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the method `readFeed`, and it should be:

```
private List<Item> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
    List<Item> items = new ArrayList();
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "rss"); // first start tag begin with <rss>
    parser.nextTag();
    parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, null, "channel");// second is <channel>
    while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) { // if encounter </channel>, stop
        if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            continue;
        }
        String name = parser.getName();
        Log.d(TAG, "start tag: " + name);
        // Starts by looking for the item tag
        if (name.equals("item")) {
            items.add(readItem(parser));
        } else {
            skipTag(parser);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```